# How to extract today, yesterday from Date() and make it localised like weekday and months?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to extract today, yesterday from date so it is localised automatically when I change language like which happens with weekdays and month.

Code for localised date that I am using:

```
let dateFormatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)
let timeStr = "00:00:00.000"

let dateString = NSString(format:"%@ %@",dateStr,timeStr)
let mainDF = Foundation.DateFormatter()
mainDF.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"
mainDF.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
mainDF.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let date = mainDF.date(from: dateString as String)
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: This will help you: https://github.com/chrisamanse/iOS-NSDate-Utilities

Comment: In I message Apple Make Today Section And When You Change the language its adopt to that language so how to make today , Yesterday Like that (Means Localised) ? Can i Extract Direct From date or any method to implement that . @dahiya_boy

Comment: @Amey Check  #Uma answer, this is how you have to do.

Comment: what output you want ? Your question is not much clear!

Comment: if i am displaying today , yesterday in my chat app when i change language to french today and yesterday should also be changed to french ? So how to achieve it . For ex if we get components from date like weekdays and months they  change thier language . So how to get today , yesterday from date ? or any other method apple does this in i message app . @Lion

Comment: are you changing device's language? I mean from setting app are you changing language or you application have this functionality ?

Comment: from Setting App I Am Changing Language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) has special flag for that: [`doesRelativeDateFormatting`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415848-doesrelativedateformatting), which renders dates in relative format, using locale set for this formatter.

> … If a date formatter uses relative date formatting, where possible it
>   replaces the date component of its output with a phrase—such as
>   “today” or “tomorrow”—that indicates a relative date. **The available
>   phrases depend on the locale for the date formatter; whereas, for
>   dates in the future, English may only allow “tomorrow,” French may
>   allow “the day after the day after tomorrow,” …**

Example:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent // Using system locale
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true // Enabling relative date formatting

// other dataFormatter settings here, irrelevant for example
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

let now = Date() 
let dateString: String = dateFormatter.string(from: now)  
print("dateString: \(dateString)") // Prints `dateString: <Today in current locale>`
```

Comment: So if i change language to spanish or any other will it support ? App Supports 10-11 Language so will it work or i have to write code to convert in every Locale ?

Comment: @Amey, it will use the locale set in your `DateFormatter`. Locales like [`.current`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293654-current) and [`.autoupdatingCurrent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293741-autoupdatingcurrent) are using locale from system settings. So if you will use them it won't need to hardcode all your supported  locales.

Comment: Can you Post Code It would be much Helpful @user28434

Comment: var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
        var date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
        var dateString: String = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        print("dateString: \(dateString)") .   This Code Works Fine Thanx A Lot